# Should I reject or approve edits which make code images visible?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

It's a good thing when users provide edits to make posts more readable and giving them the two points as reward is a good motivation. One might argue making code images visible instead of just having the "Enter image description" or "My code" link is an improvement, however code images are discouraged, so the edit might well be evaluated as non-constructive and thus worth rejecting. (I'd select "causes harm" and write a heart-warming apology to the editor explaining that asking the user to replace the image with text is a requirement for an acceptable question.)

I'd stay clear of asking anyone except the OP to replace the image with code since he or she might have the possibility to copy-and-paste it exclusively.

Example: [getting 304 error in nodejs on files like angular.min.js any other file also. but after saving files not such error comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830296/getting-304-error-in-nodejs-on-files-like-angular-min-js-any-other-file-also-bu)

Comment: No third-party edit can save that question. I'd reject those suggested edits as well.

Answer (score 7):

Code should be posted as text, not as an image. Inlining an image of code does not improve the post. So, if inlining an image is the *only* change that the editor made, you should Reject it.

You could, as you suggested, use the "causes harm" reason and explain to the editor why. That is a kind and good thing to do, although sadly I've found that few editors read the custom reject reasons, let alone learn from them. Still, no harm in trying; you can at least give them a chance to learn.

It is less clear-cut if there are more changes. Then consider if the other changes improve the post enough to Approve the edit.

If you have time to spare, you could also edit the code from the image into the post, but quite frankly, I feel that's the OP's responsibility. I consider it better to comment on the post and ask the OP to edit their post, to add their code in text form. (While you're at it, you may want to explain to them that we have a `code markdown` button in the editor, or that they can indent their code by 4 spaces.)

Comment: I strongly oppose editors turning "OCR" and changing images of code into themselves. Chances are high to introduce typos, or even introduce subtle bugs (such as getting invisible characters wrong). The questioner did the wrong thing, and he alone should be fixing this problem.